# Sed: How to enclose matching lines?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have this problem with sed.

This is what I am using:

```
sed -e "s/^00.*$/[&]\n/" file.txt
```

Trying to match occurrences of this pattern in a file:

```
00:04:33.00,00:04:37.47
```

and replace with brackets at the begin and end and a new line.

I want to get this:

```
[00:04:33.00,00:04:37.47]
<<need a new line here>>>
```

However, I am getting this:

```
]00:04:37.47,00:04:40.25
<<with a new line here>>>
```

Comment: It seems [your `sed` command yields expected result](https://ideone.com/xXlVuN)

Comment: Try with `sed -e "s/^\(00.*\)$/\[\1]\n/" file`

Comment: I was doing it from the terminal if do it in a bash script, I now get this:[00:00:14.07,00:00:18.12
] i.e, with the ']' on the new line instead.

Comment: @Ed Morton - I changed to single quotes and also they do start at the beginning of the line. They are Subviewer 2 subtitle files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the close bracket at the beginning of the line because your input file has DOS-style `\r\n` line endings. Try removing the carriage return at the end of the line first.

```
sed 's/\r$//; s/^00\..*/[&]\n/' file
```

Comment: yes, that was it. I was using a service to change the format and they apparently use that DOS-style. All is working now. I now just need to remove the '[' and ']' and I make manual changes to the file.